# How do I return the result from the addition of a and b, in a Long method?

Tags: java, methods, wrapper, long-integer, using

I'm doing an assignment for school, but I'm having trouble with wrapper conversions, I guess. I need to return the result from the addition of variables a and b, in a long method with the header like this:

```
public Long addIntegers(Integer a, Integer b) {
    …your code here…
}
```

Honestly I've been trying different things for at least a couple hours at this point.. I've looked online and I'm still very lost. I think I either might not understand the question or maybe I'm trying to do it the wrong way.

```
public class Wrapper {

public Integer x;
public Integer y;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Wrapper aWrapper = new Wrapper();
    aWrapper.addIntegers(2, 5);


}

public Long addIntegers(Integer a, Integer b) {
    Integer sum = a + b;

    return sum;
}
```

}

I expected this to work since I thought that creating and Integer variable would be able to add two int variables, but I was wrong. I've tried many other ways and the most common error is that I can't convert "x" to Long. In the case above, the error said that it couldn't convert from Integer to Long.

Comment: how do you expect that to work? you set Long as returntype, and you return an Integer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this Example

```
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Main main = new Main();
        System.out.println(main.addInteger(5, 5));
    }

    public Long addInteger(Integer a, Integer b) {
        Integer sum = a + b;
        return sum.longValue();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is incorrect. When you add 2 ints the maximum possible value cannot be held by an int so you'll get wraparound.To test this try: `addInteger(Integer.MAX_VALUE, Integer.MAX_VALUE)`, expected result is 4294967294, this method produces -2. You need to cast `a+b` to a `long`. See my answer.

Comment: @donturner Your absolutely right. addInteger(Integer.MAX_VALUE, Integer.MAX_VALUE), produces is -2 answers.

Comment: @tiescut you can used this two approaches public Long addInteger(Integer a, Integer b) {
        (1)  return (long)a + b;
        (2)  return a.longValue() + b.longValue();
    }

Answer (score 1):

Here's the simplest method:

```
public Long addIntegers(Integer a, Integer b) {
    return (long)a+b; 
}
```

What's going on?

`a` and `b` are implicitly converted to `int`s in `a+b`. Because the result of `a+b` might be larger than the maximum value of an `int` (int=32bits, long=64bits) we must explicitly cast the result to a `long`. When we return a `long` it is implicitly converted to a `Long` because of the method return type.

Comment: @azro no, he changed the type of sum

Comment: Did you try it? This does not compile. Java can't go `int` -> `long` -> `Long`. It can only ever make 1 jump implicitly.

Comment: Wow, that's embarrassing. Thanks for spotting this - fixed.

Comment: Since it is not obvious to every reader that `(long)a+b` will cast the first summand rather than the sum, I’d use `a+(long)b`, which is obvious even to readers not being familiar with the operator precedence.

Answer (score 1):

Since `a` and `b` are of `Integer` type, hence you can call `longValue` method to retrieve them as long and sum them and return the value which will be a long without needing any explicit cast.

```
public static Long addIntegers(Integer a, Integer b) {
    return a.longValue() + b.longValue();
}
```

Note, since we are adding two long values, we are also ensuring it won't run into any risk for integer overflow as addition of two large integers can possibly run into it.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> public Long addIntegers(Integer a, Integer b) {
>     Integer sum = a + b;
>
>     return sum;
> }
> ```

You're almost right with this. I can see why you'd think it would work, but you can't go from `Integer -> Long` either implicitly or via casting. You'd need to go `Integer -> int -> long -> Long`, and **Java can only make 1 jump implicitly**.

First let's take a look at what `a + b` is actually doing. It's unboxing both of `a` and `b` from `Integer`s to primitive `int`s and adding the two together, resulting in an `int`. It's then automatically boxing that to an `Integer` because that's the type of the variable `sum` you've defined.

But hang on, we can see above (`Integer -> int -> long -> Long`) that `Integer` is actually further from where we want to be, not closer!

So let's go back to `a + b`, which returns an `int`. We want a `Long`. We could cast the result to `long`:

```
public Long addIntegers(Integer a, Integer b) {
    return (long) (a + b);
}
```

In such a case, we have an `int` - the result of our sum expression - and we explicitly cast to a `long`, and Java takes the final implicit step and autoboxes this to a `Long`.

However, while casting is fine in our case, it is often a sign of bad design so I try to avoid using it where possible. Luckily, in our case we can avoid the cast. We just have to switch the implicit step and explicit steps (i.e. implicitly convert from `int -> long` and explicitly convert from `long -> Long`)

```
public Long addIntegers(Integer a, Integer b) {
    return Long.valueOf(a + b);
}
```

In this example, `Long.valueOf` takes a primitive `long` and returns a `Long` but our `a + b` calculation returns an int, so Java implicitly casts the `int` to a `long`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast the sum to `long` as :

1. (`int` + `int`) = `int` *cast to* `long`

   ```
   public Long addIntegers(Integer a, Integer b) {
       return (long) (a + b);
   }
   ```
2. (`int` *cast to* `long`) + `int` `=` `long`

   ```
   public Long addIntegers(Integer a, Integer b) {
       return (long) a + b;
   }
   ```

---

Also  :

- it seems you don't need `attributs`
- you need a local variable to save the result of the sum

```
class Wrapper {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Wrapper aWrapper = new Wrapper();
        Long res = aWrapper.addIntegers(2, 5);
    }

    public Long addIntegers(Integer a, Integer b) {
        return (long) a + b;
    }
}
```